# Why does my BMI calculator always return the user input for weight?

Tags: ruby, calculator

```
def get_values()
  puts("Please enter your height in metres.")
  height = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts("Please enter your weight in kilograms.")
  weight = gets.chomp.to_i
  bmi = ((weight).to_f / (height * height).to_f)
  puts("Your BMI is: ")
  puts bmi.to_s
end

def main()
  puts("Welcome to the BMI calculator. Would you like to continue?")
  answer = gets.chomp
  if (answer == "yes" or "Yes")
    get_values()
  else
    ("Understandable, have a nice day.")
  end
end

main()
```

If you run this, you'll see that whatever value you enter for weight, will be returned as the BMI. Why is this? I simply cannot understand why this would be. I am new to Ruby, obviously. Previously, I did not have the .to_f conversions in the calculation, but that also returned the user input value for "weight". Please help.

EDIT: Whilst I greatly appreciate the re-write of my code below, as it's a very diffferent style to my usual style of coding, I have fixed the problem with the answers below - I simply had the .to_f conversions in the wrong spot. This one works very well and is accurate to 14 decimal places!

```
def get_values()
  puts("Please enter your height in metres.")
  height = gets.to_f
  puts("Please enter your weight in kilograms.")
  weight = gets.to_f
  bmi = ((weight) / (height * height))
  puts("Your BMI is: ")
  puts bmi.to_s
end

def main()
  puts("Welcome to the BMI calculator. Would you like to continue?")
  answer = gets.chomp
  if (answer == "yes" or "Yes")
    get_values()
  else
    ("Understandable, have a nice day.")
  end
end

main()
```

EDIT: I do not remember if I changed anything relevant to the calculation, but the code has been updated again.

```
def get_values()
  puts("Please enter your height in metres.")
  height = gets.to_f
  puts("Please enter your weight in kilograms.")
  weight = gets.to_f
  bmi = ((weight) / (height * height))
  puts("Your BMI is: ")
  puts bmi.to_s
  return bmi
end

def harsh_truths()
  bmi = get_values()
  if (bmi < 18.5)
    puts("You are underweight.")
  elsif (bmi > 18.5) and (bmi < 25.0)
    puts("You are a healthy weight.")
  elsif (bmi > 25) and (bmi < 30)
    puts("You are overweight.")
  elsif (bmi > 30)
    puts("You are obese.")
  end
end

def main()
  puts("Welcome to the BMI calculator. Would you like to continue?")
  answer = gets.chomp
  if (answer == "yes") or (answer == "Yes")
    harsh_truths()
  else
    ("Understandable, have a nice day.")
  end
end

main()
```

The above is the "updated code" that I keep referring to. I hope to see you all again when I add the option to calculate BMI using imperial values.

Comment: Presumably because your height is between 1 and 2 metres. What does `.to_i` do to e.g. `1.5`?

Comment: You can just do `x.to_f` if there's only one term, there's no need for `(x).to_f`.

Comment: Tip: Use `gets.to_f`, the `chomp` doesn't do anything useful, the newline is ignored anyway.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a `main` function and defining one goes against a lot of conventions. That aside, empty argument lists are also omitted, so `def main()` should be `def main` and `main()` should be just `main`. The less clutter there is in your Ruby code, the better.

Comment: @tadman interesting, we were taught to use `def main()` at university, and it was mentioned that certain characters could be omitted from Ruby but this was never brought up. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ruby's not like C or Java, and making it look like either ends up with a mess of code that's not very Ruby. What's taught in university tends to be highly opinion-based, often those of the professor teaching it, and some have very, very unusual opinions. Think of the "When in Rome" principle, and code accordingly. Each language has its own natural way to approach problems and express solutions.

Comment: @GrumpyKaren : Simple mathematics: Unless the user is taller than 2 meters, `height` in your program will be always be `1`. Hence your BMI formula calculates `bmi = weight / (1*1)`, which means that `bmi` equals `weight`.  If you enter i.e. 5 for the height, you will find a different outcome.

Comment: @user1934428 I found that when entering a value of 5.0 for height, and a value of 300 for weight, the output was 12.0. This was using the updated code. I have checked this against an online BMI calculator and found the result to be exactly the same. Are you referring to my original code?

Comment: @tadman our professor was so obsesssed with C, that he dedicated the last week of our Ruby course to teaching us "hello world" in C. I have no idea what language my code looks like (probably just spaghetti) but that would make sense - most of the Ruby code I see on Github and such looks nothing like mine, or anything I was taught in the course. However, we were told that we were learning "structured programming" - am I just seeeing OOP everywhere or am I missing something here?

Comment: Ruby is very unusual as far as languages go in that it's *heavily* object-oriented, as in pretty much everything is an object, a property on an object, or both. This is not the case in others like C++ or Java. It's also exceptionally expressive, which is why I mention these little syntax issues, in its simplest form Ruby is very elegant. Done the C way, which is allowed, it's as clunky and bizarre looking.

Comment: "Structured Programming" is a term from the 1980s that is such an anachronism. It's in opposition to "Spaghetti Programming" which is what happened when people could use `goto` without consequences, or assembly code with jumps all over the place. Arguably all programming is structured now by default unless you go out of your way to  confuse things.

Comment: @GrumpyKaren: I had not seen your updates yet. If you update a question, it is in general better to just amend it with new information, and not change the existing text. If you change the text of your question, comments and answers may become meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed, more idiomatic Ruby version of the same code:

```rb
# Define a generic method to grab input
def ask(prompt)
  puts prompt
  gets.to_f
end

# Loop while more input is available
loop do
  # puts doesn't always use brackets, it's subjective. You can, but
  # in many cases they're omitted for simplicity.
  puts("Welcome to the BMI calculator. Would you like to continue?")

  case (gets.chomp)
  when /\An/i # Anything that "starts with" (\A) "n" + case insensitive (/i)
    puts "Understandable, have a nice day."
    break
  end

  # Get some input
  height = ask("Please enter your height in metres.")
  weight = ask("Please enter your weight in kilograms.")

  # Notice how if they're already float this becomes super easy
  bmi = weight / (height * height)

  # Use string interpolation, automatic .to_s conversion happens.
  puts "Your BMI is: #{bmi}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Our professor at university taught us to write code in a very different style to this, so seeing examples of code written in this style is very helpfull. Do you know if there's a name for it? We were supposedly taught "structured programming" but the professor had some unusual ideas regarding Ruby, as has been pointed out in the comments above. Buut this looks much cleaner, and less bloated than the way I was taught.

Comment: It's just "Idiomatic Ruby", where every language their own "idiomatic" form that the community tends to steer towards. Sometimes this is enforced by the compiler or a linter, like [JSLint](https://jslint.com), or Go, which can be very particular about pretty much everything. Ruby has [Rubocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/) which will complain *vigorously* about your code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just change height and `weight` to `float` as follow:

```
height = gets.chomp.to_f

weight = gets.chomp.to_f
```

Comment: `gets.to_f` is sufficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's what I ended up doing, right before I saw your comment. But thank you!